# Реализация метода из интерфейса/абстрактного класса (API Java)

Tags: java, api, интерфейс

В общем, есть интерфейс, разумеется, чтобы использовать его методы - нужно их реализовать (как говорит программа и в принципе насколько мне известно). Для примера:

```
interface chto{
    public void to();
    public void eto();
}

class Caty implements chto{
    @Override
    public void to(){
        System.out.println("to");
    }
    @Override
    public void eto(){
        System.out.println("eto");
    }
}
```

Аналогично и с абстрактными классами.
Так вот вопрос, как реализовать методы из API Java? Как мне понять, что именно необходимо там сделать? Просто создать переменные такого же типа и приравнять их значение к значению в описании?

Если так - как в таком случае это работает, не совсем понимаю. Если в интерфейсе у методов изначально нет тела, грубо говоря, они просто объявляются. Как тогда выполняются действия, которые просто не описаны в коде метода

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы умеете управлять автомобилем (взаимодействовать с интерфейсом). Для этого вам нужны методы

- Повернуть
- Ускориться
- Затормозить

Как эти методы реализованы в конкретном автомобиле (в конкретном классе) - вас не интересует.

Более того этот же интерфейс можно реализовать для симулятора. Конструкция принципиально другая, а интерфейс тот же и управлять им вы умеете.

Т.е. обращаетесь вы к методу интерфейса, а что этот метод делает - определяет класс, который этот интерфейс реализует

Например, есть интерфейс `List`. Этот интерфейс реализует два класса

- `ArrayList` - хранит элементы в массиве
- `LinkedList` - хранит элементы в связном списке

Вы определяете, какая реализация вам подходит больше и создаете объект нужного класса

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

После этого вы можете работать со списком не заботясь о внутреннем хранении